# PHP: move_uploaded_file doesn't work

Tags: php, file, file-io, io

I just want to move a temporary file to a specified folder. Here is my code.

```
        $uploads_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload';
        $name = basename($_FILES["csv"]["name"]);
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"];
        chmod("{$uploads_dir}/{$name}", 0755);

        if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "{$uploads_dir}/{$name}")):
            array_push($fileErrArr, "fail to move uploaded file");
        endif;
```

This is the error message from the httpd log. It doesn't even mention the "permission" stuff.

[error] [client XXX] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/upload/XXX.csv): failed to open stream: \xe8\xa8\xb1\xe5\x8f\xaf\xe3\x81\x8c\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x82\x8a\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x9b\xe3\x82\x93 in /var/www/html/XXX/action.php on line 115, referer: https://XXX/

[error] [client XXX] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php40tPEO' to '/var/www/html/upload/XXX.csv' in /var/www/html/XXX/action.php on line 115, referer: https://XXX/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does your target dir have the right privilege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` to check your PHP script runner.

Then use `ls -l` to check the target direction who is the owner.

Make sure the runner and the owner is the same.

Eg: the php runner may be www-data and the target folder owner may be admin. Use:

```
chown www-data /var/www/xxx/upload
chmod 755 /var/www/xxx/upload
```

It may work.

Comment: checked with whoami. It was "apache" but the owner is "vagrant". Even I did this: chown apache /var/www/xxx/upload. Still didn't work

Comment: Can you use absolute path rather than relative path? Try to let your $tmp_name be the absolute path.

Comment: chmod the upload folder to 777?

Comment: tried both 755, 777. didn't work. btw, the environment is vagrant centos 6.5 running on mac os 10.13 and the synced folder for uploaded file is set to enable to be written on mac.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Everyone I did encountered this error lately, I am also a beginner and solved this problem in just 3 hours this is the thing that helps me. I use Linux AMI EC2 intance.

The problem might be all about the "Writeability"(sorry I am not really familiar with terms please bear with me) permission of the folder maybe it is only allowed for the root

First make a script on the live serve  and include this code to know what is the name 
of the client that will execute the move_uploaded_file command of php

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');    
?>
```

Then it results to give me "apache" as my client's user
After it look for the folder the destination check if it is writeable by the client's side
using

ls -lh /var/www/folder/

then you will see like
the root and www on it
change it to

chown -R apache:apache /folder destination

Always take note that the user is the result of whoami php script

Hope this helps